# Links not working in UITextView Attributed String when language is Arabic

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, arabic

We have implemented a code to add a link to the whole attributed text inside a UITextView.

The strings we are loading are:

English String: "Click Here To View",
Arabic String:  "انقر هنا للعرض"

```
func setupTextView() {
  let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "")
  let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: {string value}, attributes: 
  [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:Colors.gray_3_748499])
  mutableAttributedString.append(attributedString)
  mutableAttributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.link, value: 
    "https://www.google.com", range: NSMakeRange(0, self.attributedString.length))

  self.textView.attributedText = mutableAttributedString
}
```

Result:We can see that for all other required languages, on clicking the text, the delegate 
`textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction)` is called but not for Arabic.

Looking forward for valuable suggestions.

Comment: Implemented the same in my app, it is working perfect. Hope you have set textview delegate and added RTL support.

Comment: I think that you should create a style and add the alignment property: paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentRight. And add this style to your attributed string.

Comment: @Catherine  This code is working for me when the language of the content is English, French, Spanish, Russian, etc. But not working for Arabic.

Comment: @RazvanS.Yes I added the Paragraph style and the alignment changed to right. But that is not the issue I am facing. I have added the whole content inside the textview as a link and I am not able to select the link if the contents are in Arabic language. It works fine for all other languages.

Comment: Yes I understand, but it worked for Arabic also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue. 
I have been overriding the

`func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool`

method to ignore the taps anywhere but not the links in a textview.

I was using a UITextLayoutDirection as left inside this method. I had to change it according to the alignment for different languages. That is for Right to Left languages, I will use the UITextLayoutDirection.Right.

Thanks